# want to get difference between two values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i want to get difference between two values. i get my last entered value in bill no and get difference with input value.

this is my controller function model

```
$restPaymentSales = DB::table('sales')
                    ->select('rest_payment')
                    ->where('bill_no', $request->input('bill_no')) 
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->first(); 

$payment = $request->input('payment');    

$doubleVal = doubleval($payment);
```

and i wrote calculation like this

```
$restSales = $restPaymentSales->child['rest_payment'] - $doubleVal;
```

but it shows me this error

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

my table row like this

```
rest_payment -> double(11,2)
```

how can i fix this issue. basically i want to get difference between table last value order by date and input value.

Comment: try this.. $restSales = $restPaymentSales->rest_payment - $doubleVal;

Comment: any diff from my comment ?

Comment: @TOH19 i do this but same error

Comment: @KalanaMihiranga - Can you `print_r($restPaymentSales)` and show us the output?

Comment: @TOH19 {#255 ▼
  +"rest_payment": 500.0
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your calculation from:

```
$restSales = $restPaymentSales->child['rest_payment'] - $doubleVal;
```

TO

```
$restSales = $restPaymentSales->rest_payment - $doubleVal;
```

Comment: can you do a ```dd($restPaymentSales);``` after the query to see the contents of the variable.

Comment: {#255 ▼
  +"rest_payment": 500.0
}

Comment: shows me this error - Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: just out of curiosity what is the output of ```dd($restPaymentSales->rest_payment);``` ?

Comment: I guess the issue is here... can you ```dd(doubleval($payment));```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189902/discussion-between-vidal-and-kalana-mihiranga).